# Web app folder structure

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, website

Hot to organize web app folder?

This is example that I use with my common projects:

```
/home/webmaster/www/sitename.com/
                    └── doc # documentation, helpful information
                    └── log # folder for server logs for that website
                    └── htdocs # folder for app
                        # In case of Laravel
                        # └── app
                        # └── bootstrap
                        # └── public
                        # ...
                    └── backup
                    └── ...
```

But when I use some framework like Laravel I had project name htdocs, which is not very semantic and meaningful. What approach do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I would usually advice you to use a framework and stick to their structure. For example, with Laravel 4, you have all the logic inside the `app` folder and the website under the `public`folder

This are guys that have put a lot of work in their structure, so I would recommend you to go with it.

Comment: You mean put all folders (log,doc etc.) inside Laravel app folder and use it as root folder? (www/sitename/public,vendor,log and others)

Comment: Laravel has its own log files and functions. Why not use those? For documentation, you can use what you wish, even though I would use the app folder

Answer (score 0):

Whatever works for you and gets documented...

The only thing I really care about is that web applications can be installed in and/or accessed from an arbitrary subdirectory and don't expect exclusive use of the root directory.